# How to make slanted ribbon

Tags: html, css, css-shapes, css-transforms

How to create a ribbon like the below image using CSS. I know how to make the slanted filled box with text in it, but I struggle with the flaps.

[image]

Here's [codepen link](http://cdpn.io/zwDir)

Comment: why dont you try this? http://www.css3d.net/ribbon-generator/ it may help you a lot..try and explore about the possibilities

Comment: Please don't add solution details to the question mate. I have removed it from the question and have temporarily added it to my own answer to make sure your update isn't lost. I shall have it removed in case you want to make it a different answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Below is a sample of how you can do this. It is basically made with one parent `div` which has the ribbon text and two other `div` to produce the folded portions of the ribbon at the top and bottom. The folded portions are positioned according to the needs.

[image]

```css
body {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #FFF;
}
.container {
  margin: 50px 100px;
}
.ribbon {
  position: absolute;
  width: 400px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #000;
  padding: 20px 5px 20px 5px;
  -webkit-transform: skew(1deg, -15deg);
  -moz-transform: skew(1deg, -15deg);
  -o-transform: skew(1deg, -15deg);
  -ms-transform: skew(1deg, -15deg);
  transform: skew(1deg, -15deg);
  /* Note: The best practice is to always add the un-prefixed standards version as last */
}
.ribbon_before {
  height: 25px;
  width: 50px;
  position: relative;
  border: 2px solid black;
  top: 116px;
  left: 2px;
}
.ribbon_after {
  height: 25px;
  width: 50px;
  position: relative;
  border: 2px solid black;
  top: -56px;
  left: 355px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class='ribbon_before'>&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="ribbon">LOREM IPSUM DOLOR SIT AMET</div>
  <div class='ribbon_after'>&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

[**Demo on CodePen**](http://codepen.io/hari_shanx/pen/Fvtmy)

---

**Note:** The same effect can be achieved by using just a single `div` and a couple of pseudo-elements also like shown in the below snippet.

```css
body {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #FFF;
}
.ribbon {
  margin: 100px 100px;
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #000;
  padding: 20px 5px 20px 5px;
  -webkit-transform: skew(1deg, -15deg);
  -moz-transform: skew(1deg, -15deg);
  -o-transform: skew(1deg, -15deg);
  -ms-transform: skew(1deg, -15deg);
  transform: skew(1deg, -15deg);
}
.ribbon:before {
  height: 25px;
  width: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  border: 2px solid black;
  bottom: -8px;
  left: 0px;
  -webkit-transform: skew(-1deg, 15deg);
  -moz-transform: skew(-1deg, 15deg);
  -o-transform: skew(-1deg, 15deg);
  -ms-transform: skew(-1deg, 15deg);
  transform: skew(-1deg, 15deg);
}
.ribbon:after {
  height: 25px;
  width: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  border: 2px solid black;
  top: -8px;
  right: 0px;
  -webkit-transform: skew(-1deg, 15deg);
  -moz-transform: skew(-1deg, 15deg);
  -o-transform: skew(-1deg, 15deg);
  -ms-transform: skew(-1deg, 15deg);
  transform: skew(-1deg, 15deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="ribbon">LOREM IPSUM DOLOR SIT AMET</div>
```

---

**Solution Tweaked by OP to meet their needs:**

I've tweaked the code a little to elevate it to condition close to 'pixel perfect' and here's the final link http://cdpn.io/zwDir

Comment: @ncubica: Blame it on my eyesight :D By the way, is it off in both samples mate?